# How to respond to "What have you been doing these days?"

Tags: grammaticality

What could I say if someone meet me after the 6th month, he would say

> Hey! What do you do these days or what have you been doing  these days?

could I say ;

1. I read an English books  these days.
2. I am reading an English book these days .

Which one is correct?

Comment: Please make the title clearer.  A title like "British Englisj" doesn't describe the content of the question.  I have edited your question to make it better.

Comment: We ask, "What are you doing these days?" or "What have you been doing recently?" The first question asks about something ongoing: usually your job. The second is about things you may have finished.

Comment: _These days_ implies that it is a long time since they have met or updated each other. _At the moment_ would be more normal if it is not the first conversation in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The better question would be "What have you been doing?"

You can answer with

> "I have been ...ing ..."

You read many books.  So you might say

> I have been reading English books.

This is the simple answer. But there are lots of ways to answer the question. and native speakers probably won't have a simple answer, because you have been doing lots of things in six months.